# How to connect to a Google Cloud SQL database using Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, hikaricp

I am in the process of making my database cloud based, however I'm having trouble connecting to it. I have followed this

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#java

I think the problem is I am having problems setting up HikariCP in my Java project. As I keep getting the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
```

So if anyone has any solutions, either fixing the problem above, or a new way about it I would be very grateful.

Comment: it just seems like a missing dependency, you are running the sample project from GooleCloudPlatform? if you are using a maven project `    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [github for Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) or the MySQL/Postgres JDBC and R2DBC drivers which allows the user with proper permission to connect to a Cloud SQL database.